# Gnome Desktop internal HDD position moves

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, shortcuts

I have added an HDD to my laptop, what I mount with the ON shortcut on startup, when I need it (otherwise it just makes too much vibrations and noise).

Each time I mount it, the shortcut for HDD "KohutavaltVana" Moves down and right in random amounts.
Picture: It should be between "OFF" & "Keep", but has moved.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: any idea of how to get rid of it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

Mounted drives will usually appear randomly on the desktop, you may just click and drag the icon and position it as you wish... You can also right-click desktop and disable the 'keep aligned' option.

Comment: I have the keep aligned disabled, so I can align with wallpaper, that's why it even bothers me...